# Implementation method for enabling/disabling push notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notifications using FCM in my Flutter app.
Next, I want to allow users to control the ON/OFF state of receiving push notifications based on their content (similar to receiving push notifications for "likes" on their own posts in a social media app) from the Flutter app (client) side.

I couldn't find a specific implementation method while researching, so I would like to ask here for advice on how to achieve this.

The method I have considered is to save the settings for each user's push notification items in Firestore. During push notification sending, the app will check the saved values and decide whether to include the notification in the payload based on those values.

However, this approach requires storing data for each push notification item (e.g., "like" or "mention") in Firestore, and there will be multiple communications with Firestore each time the client changes the push notification settings. This could result in increased network communication and overhead.

So, besides the method of saving the push notification enable/disable value in Firestore and checking it every time an FCM message is sent, are there any other methods to determine whether to perform push notifications on the client side for each push notification item?